# How to parse a POST request's body

Tags: http, parsing, post, parameters

I need to parse a POST request, specifically its parameters. The way I understand it is that the body of the request contains either a list of parameters in the form of `key1=value&key2=value` or other data, like an uploaded file. Is there a way to be certain about what I get (parameters or file data)?

A quick solution could be regex, but a file might also contain data in the form of `key1=value&key2=value`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to be certain about what I get (parameters or file data)?

Yes, but not from the body. You need to read the request header `Content-Type`.

If it's `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, you've got the complex MIME multipart syntax that can contain file data.

If it's `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you've got the query-string-like parameters.

If it's something else (eg `application/json`), you've got a custom POST request being fired by something other than a straight form submission, in which case it's up to you to decide what that format is.